# count multiple list elements in line in python 3

Tags: string, list, python-3.x

I have a list of names and a .txt file full of multiple names per line.  For each line, I need to strip away the names not contained in my list.

For example:

```
namelist=[Jill,Joe,Jeff,Jim]
sampleline="Greg L,George C,Jill J,Joe F,Jeff B,Fred M"
```

My desired output:

```
"Jill,Joe,Jeff"
```

I am totally lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `namelist` will only contain first names, then this should do:

```
import re

namelist = ["Jill", "Joe", "Jeff", "Jim"] 
sampleline="Greg L,George C,Jill J,Joe F,Jeff B,Fred M"

r = set(re.split(r'\s|,', sampleline)) & set(namelist)
final = ','.join(r)
print(final)
# 'Jeff,Joe,Jill'
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple approach is just to split each first name apart, and check if it exists in the target set:

```
# braces make this a set, for theoretically faster lookup as the name "list" grows
namelist = {'Jill', 'Joe', 'Jeff', 'Jim'}
sampleline="Greg L,George C,Jill J,Joe F,Jeff B,Fred M"

# Split up by commas first, then keep only the first name by splitting on whitespace
# and dropping all but first component
firstnames = (name.split(None, 1)[0] for name in sampleline.split(','))

# Iterate first names and keep the ones in the target set
foundnames = ','.join(name for name in firstnames if name in namelist)
# Alt: ','.join(filter(namelist.__contains__, firstnames))
```